# todayToken .sol not compiling on remix ethereum - getting error with import “./EIP20Interface.sol”; ?? ANY SOLUTION IDEAS?

Tags: error

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

import “./EIP20Interface.sol”;

contract TodayTOKEN is EIP20Interface {

    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

    string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
    uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show.
    string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX

    function todayTOKEN(
        uint256 _initialAmount,
        string _tokenName,
        uint8 _decimalUnits,
        string _tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
        name = _tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        symbol = _tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        }
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `EIP20Interface.sol` located in the same directory as your `todayToken.sol` contract? The './' notation implies that EIP20Interface.sol is in the same directory.
Also, I'm not sure if it's just how you pasted the text in your question but the quotation marks around `“./EIP20Interface.sol”;` are odd characters. Try this: `import "./EIP20Interface.sol";`

Comment: I will try it and revert. Thank you